# How did the Palace of Poitiers change from its depiction in Tres Riches Heures to now?

Tags: middle-ages, france, castles

They seem completely different so I'm really confused how they could be the same structure.Is there anything left of what was depicted in the manuscript?

[Tres Riches Heures](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Les_Tr%C3%A8s_Riches_Heures_du_duc_de_Berry_juillet.jpg)

[Now](https://www.google.com/search?q=palace+of+poitiers+overhead&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjKsfXp44X2AhVeA50JHX_GD_0Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=palace+of+poitiers+overhead&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECAAQHlAAWL8LYLgMaABwAHgAgAFEiAHCBJIBATmYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=174NYorqBN6G9PwP_4y_6A8&bih=995&biw=1920&client=firefox-b-1-d&hl=en#imgrc=QDgkEiShhvbHfM&imgdii=biGuOW162Zl1-M) (sorry couldn't find better photo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [French wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A2teau_triangulaire_de_Poitiers), what is depicted in the Tres Riches Heures is a different castle, which was also located in Poitiers and demolished in 1591.